# Dynamodb scan "Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead" when filtering on decimal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, dynamodb-queries

I'm stumped on this one..

this is my scan:

```
        response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('ttl').gte(Decimal(time.time()-900)) & Attr('SessionStatus').eq('failed'))
```

Yet when I run it, I get error: `Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DynamoDB, float types are not directly supported, and it's recommended to use Decimal types instead to maintain precision when working with decimal numbers. Try the code below instead

```py
import boto3
import time
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
from decimal import Decimal

# Initialize DynamoDB client
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='YOUR_REGION')

# Function to perform the scan
def scan_with_filter():
    try:
        # Calculate the time threshold for 15 minutes ago
        time_threshold = Decimal(str(time.time() - 900))  # 900 seconds = 15 minutes

        # Define scan parameters with the updated FilterExpression
        scan_params = {
            'TableName': 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME',
            'FilterExpression': Attr('ttl').gte(time_threshold) & Attr('SessionStatus').eq('failed')
        }

        response = dynamodb_client.scan(**scan_params)

        # Process scanned items
        items = response.get('Items', [])
        print("Scanned items:", items)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error scanning DynamoDB table:", e)

# Perform the scan with the specified FilterExpression
scan_with_filter()
```

Comment: Thanks, trying now.  I notice you first parse `time.time()` to str?  Why won't `number` to `Decimal` work?  Why must we route through str?

Comment: This worked, but I'm not sure if it was the `number` to `str` to `Decimal` translation or the moving of params to a var.  I don't have time to test these combos right now, but thanks

Comment: Glad it helped out man.